# Angular Flex Layout gap changing

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I`ve got a problem with fxLayoutGap. When I dynamically change document direction, gap`s margins didn`t changes. Can I fix this, or this haven`t solution?

**stackblitz:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjuyuv

Comment: Hi, can you show your code?

Comment: @AbedPutra it\`s on stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fxLayoutGap` just adds `margin-bottom` or `margin-right` style attributes, depending on `fxLayout` value. You need to change a style attribute dynamically also, or, that is much better, take another solution.

Comment: can I reload layout gaps? or something like this

Comment: no, write your own styles. It isn't so difficult as it seems.